# How to Mysqli Query Specific Records first?

Tags: mysql

I have a query and in this query it brings back results from my userTable just fine. However, I am trying to figure out a way to show profiles from our University first then display the results after. What would be the best method?

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE keyID LIKE '%".getID."%' 
ORDER BY Lname ASC"
```

My db has a column called 'education' which displays the university from which the profile came from. We would like to sort using our university first then display the other results after.

Comment: Please, provide table structure and sample data through sqlfiddle

Comment: Did you finally get it to work @MizAkita?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE keyID LIKE '%".getID."%' 
ORDER BY Education ASC, Lname ASC"
```

This will order the "education" in a ascending order from a-z

Edit

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE keyID LIKE '%".getID."%' 
CASE WHEN Education = 'ThisUniv' then 1 else 2 end,education, Lname ASC"
```

Change Yale to then name of your university

Comment: But it doesn't guarantee, that the records from the necessary university will come first

Comment: Thats true. Will wait to get more info from @MizAkita

Comment: Well i know i can order by education but OUR university would need to be first so could it be something like 'ORDER BY Education = "ThisUniv" ASC...?

Comment: Saw i use university as column name, changed it now to education

Comment: CAn you please put the table definition on here and the full sql code_

Comment: @MizAkita , could you provide the additional data?

Comment: What type of addn'l data? I am trying to show Education="ThisUniv" (our university) first when queried. The other Universities would display after these...

Comment: Please show me your entire statement, you said you get a syntax error, so i think your query is not correct written.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. you give a rank to the ones you wish to display first over the rank you give to the ones you wish to display later. This is not a very efficient query.

```
SELECT innerquery.*
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS RANK,
               u1.*
          FROM userTable u1
         WHERE u1.keyID LIKE '%".getID."%'
           AND education = 'my uni'
      ORDER BY u1.Lname ASC
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS RANK,
               u2.*
          FROM userTable u2
         WHERE u2.keyID LIKE '%".getID."%'
           AND education <> 'my uni'
      ORDER BY u2.Lname ASC
      ) innerquery
ORDER BY RANK, Lname asc
```

Comment: It easier to apply a case when in the order clause IMHO.